# Как в foreach обратиться к массиву по ссылке?

Tags: php

Структура такая:

```
arr [
    inner1[],
    inner2[],
    ...
]
```

Прохожу циклом по массиву `arr`:

```
foreach ($arr as $inner) {
    $inner[...] = ...;
}
```

В общем, произвожу действия со вложенным массивом, но так понимаю, что значение `$inner` в `foreach` не является указателем на вложенный массив, поэтому в самом массиве изменений не производится.

Единственным вариантом вижу проход по массиву обычным циклом и обращение к каждому элементу по индексу. Это, и правда, единственный вариант?

Comment: переменная $inner при foreach уже содержит значение inner1 и inner2, что у вас не получается получить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr as &$inner) {
     $inner[...] = ...;
}
```

Comment: Добавлю. После этого цикла желательно выполнить unset($inner);

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать array_map(callback, array) для применения функнии calback ко всем элементам массива.

```
function mycallback($v)
{
    $v=strtoupper($v);
    return $v;
}

$a=array("Animal" => "horse", "Type" => "mammal");
array_map("mycallback", $a)
```

вернет

```
Array ( [Animal] => HORSE [Type] => MAMMAL )
```

Тут пример использования https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_map.asp

Если, по каким-то критериям, нужно удалить часть массива, можно использовать array_filter(array, callback)

```
function test_odd($var)
{
    return($var & 1);
}

$a1=array("a","b",2,3,4);
array_map($a1, "test_odd")
```

вернет

```
Array ( [3] => 3 )
```

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_filter.asp